Kong Ingress Controller with SSL Self-Signed Certificate
I have tried the guide on the Kong official documentation but I am still not able to create a connection between frontend react pod to https Kong Ingress Controller backend. Currently Im using a self-signed certificate and I believe I am able to do the above using a trusted CA provider but Im just curious if self-signed CA can be used in such a way or not?
https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/guides/services/https-redirect/
This is what I have done so far
ingressClassName: testing
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: <service name>
            port:
              number: 8000
        path: /<service-name>
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - <IP Address>
    secretName: testing

The result that I have currently by triggering this:
$ curl --cacert server.crt https://<ip-address>
* Connected to <ip-address> (<ip-address>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: server.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Please tell if I do it in a correct way or not.
